# How to sort fields by date in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, firebase, sorting, google-cloud-firestore, key-value

I need some help with finding out how to sort these Arrays by the date which is given in Seconds and then converted into date using the .toDate function.

```
const todoList = document.querySelector('.upcoming ul');
            const generateTemplate = (todo, date) => {
                const html = `<h5 style="padding-top: 5px; font-weight: 375; margin-top: auto;">${date}</h5><li>
                ${todo} 
                </li>`
                todoList.innerHTML += html;
            };

            let events = [];


            db.collection("Users").doc(user.uid).get().then((doc) => {
                var gid = doc.get("group");

                db.collection("Groups").doc(gid).get()
                    .then((document) => {
                        var fields = Object.keys(document.data());
                        var dates = Object.values(document.data());
                        console.log(fields);
                        console.log(dates);

                        const options = { weekday: 'long', year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric' };

                        fields.forEach(field => {
                            var date = document.get(field).toDate().toLocaleDateString('de-DE', options)
                            var now = new Date();

                            if (document.get(field).toDate() < now) {
                                var path = db.collection("Groups").doc(gid);
                                path.update({
                                    [field]: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.delete()
                                });
                            }
                            generateTemplate(field, date);
                        });
                    });


            });
```

I'm not sure how to solve this problem because I'm using a forEach loop to add all the innerHTML to the list.

[This is the list and the outputs for the fields and the dates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IEMeS.png)

If you need any further information please reply. I'm still pretty new to stackoverflow and the whole programming community since I'm just 14.

Thank you for helping!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the array sort before you map over the fields like here:

```js
db.collection("Groups")
  .doc(gid)
  .get()
  .then((document) => {
    var fields = Object.keys(document.data());
    var dates = Object.values(document.data());
    console.log(fields);
    console.log(dates);

    const options = {
      weekday: "long",
      year: "numeric",
      month: "long",
      day: "numeric",
    };

    fields
      .sort(function (a, b) {

        return document
          .get(b).seconds - document
          .get(a).seconds;
      })
      .map((field) => {
        var date = document
          .get(field)
          .toDate()
          .toLocaleDateString("de-DE", options);
        var now = new Date();

        if (document.get(field).toDate() < now) {
          var path = db.collection("Groups").doc(gid);
          path.update({
            [field]: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.delete(),
          });
        }
        generateTemplate(field, date);
      });
  });
```

Comment: I tried this solution but unfortuantely it still just sorts the list randomly.

Comment: can you try to log the list before and after the sort?

Comment: Yes I logged the list before it was sorted and then once in the map function here are the resulsts

Output and code: https://imgur.com/a/Mce49Ew

Comment: Can you pls log `dateA` and `dateB` just to check if we get proper dates out there.

Comment: Here is the output when I log both dates https://imgur.com/a/g2sQfGs

Comment: OK. It looks like we don't get the right dates because they are all the same (today). Did you log before `new Date()` or after it? Could you pls log the raw data. I think we just use wrong data for the sort

Comment: I logged the two dates before the return new Date

Comment: Can you try it with more different dates? Those right now are 3 times the same and then another one. And they are now sorted as they should be.

Comment: I added another one and now you can see that it is not in the correct order anymore https://imgur.com/a/UgtX7Wx

Comment: Could you send me the value of `document.data()` and I can try it on my side.

Comment: Can you pls directly copy the object as json here. It's a little bit hard for me to write the data from your screenshots.

Comment: {
  " Testing Sort 3": {
    "seconds": 1627603200,
    "nanoseconds": 0
  },
  "Testing Sort 1": {
    "seconds": 1627689600,
    "nanoseconds": 0
  },
  " Testing Sort 4": {
    "seconds": 1627516800,
    "nanoseconds": 0
  },
  " Testing Sort 2": {
    "seconds": 1627516800,
    "nanoseconds": 0
  }
}

Comment: I have updated the answer. Can you check it pls again.

Comment: Great to hear that. It would be nice if you could mark the answer as accepted and upvote it :)

Comment: I can mark it as the answer but I already tried to upvote and I'm sorry but my reputation is not high enough but I'll make sure that I can upvote it as soon as I get 15 rep